# Early returning from a base web api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have this controller:

```
public class TestController : ODataControllerBase<TestModel, Test>
{
    public IEnumerable<TestModel> Get()
    {
        var results = Tests.Get();

        return new PageResult<TestModel>(results);
    }
}
```

Which has this base controller:

```
public abstract class ODataControllerBase<TModel, TEntity> : ODataController
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);

        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Test"))
        {
            base.Ok(new List<TModel>());
        }
    }
}
```

This base is inherited from multiple controllers and it all works.

Except the part where it checks if the user is in the right role. When the user is not it goes in the `base.Ok(new List<TModel>());` part, but thats it. It skips by and then continues with the `Get()` action and returns the results anyway.

How can I make sure that the base controller set the response context and prevents any further actions from running?

Comment: This logic should probably be in an attribute that you apply to your class. You can set it up so that if the user isn't in the role it won't even enter your Get() method.

Comment: You should be able to replace that role check code with `[Authorize(Roles = "Test")]` on the class or individual actions.

Comment: @DavidG I can't because I have to be able to return an empty list instead of an error code, that's how the frontend part works.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan I tried this at first, but because you can't use generics in attributes I had to abandon this plan quickly.

Comment: I don't understand why you're going so far out of your way to make the front end happy. The front end should be able to handle cases where an error comes back and it doesn't have an empty list, if it needs an empty list to operate it should check if the model is null and create an empty list to work off of.

Comment: If you can modify your front end you could make this very clean by inheriting from `ActionFilterAttribute` and overriding `OnActionExecuting`

Comment: @TheMuffinMan the frontend consists of a complex syncing part based on JayData that communicates with OData. Unfortunately it's not easy to modify this behavior as it comes from the 3rd party libraries.